# How do I display data from a SQL Server database based on checked box in VB.Net?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I need to retrieve data from SQL Server based on a checkbox list in VB.Net. When I check an item, all rows which contain that item must be displayed in a DataGridView. How do I make this happen?

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You need to try out some solution. StackOverflow is not code suggesting website, its for solving problems faced.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
Select column1, column2 
from tablename 
where columnname= '"& checkbox.text& "'
```

That must filter your database.

Comment: oh, sorry, my bad. i've fixed it.

Comment: Writing in ALL CAPS is equivalent to **SHOUTING** at your readers, which is just plain rude - don't do it - please fix your post right now

Comment: sorry, i wont do it again

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get all selected items in the checkbox:

```
For Each checkBox As CheckBox In chkbxlst.Items
    If (checkBox.Checked = True) Then
        'its selected
    End If
Next
```

Next, write a SQL query,

```
select * from tablename where column in ({0})
```

We can go parameterized way or non-parameterized way. Parameterized is recommended to avoid SQL Injection attack.

```
Dim query as String = "select * from tablename where column in ({0})"
Dim i as Int = 0
Dim sqlCommand = new SqlCommand()
sqlCommand.Connection = connection
sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
Dim sb = new new List<string>()
For Each checkBox As CheckBox In chkbxlst.Items
    If (checkBox.Checked = True) Then
        Dim paramName as String = "paramName" + i
        sb.Append(paramName)
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, checkBox.Text)
    End If
Next
sqlCommand.CommandText = String.Format(query, string.Join(",", sb))
'..execute the command and get response
```